# Question regarding printing out results for python system

Tags: python

I have these two files in Python

```
x = pandas.read_csv('x.csv', header=0, parse_dates=True)
y = pandas.read_csv('y.csv', header=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Produce columns like so

```
 yyyymm  cons_sent
0    200001      112.0
1    200002      111.3
2    200003      107.1
3    200004      109.2
 yyyymm  inv_sent
0    200001      0.58
1    200002      0.53
2    200003      0.90
```

Another file, known as `z.csv`, prints out as you see below. How do I get it so that this z.csv prints out just `yyyymm` and the score column (and not everything else)?

```
yyyymm  count_neg  count_pos  count_all     score
0  200002        135        111      12397  0.001936
1  200003        111         82       8969  0.003233
2  200005        140         67       8505  0.008583
```

After that is accomplished, how to get all three files in one? That is, how can I merge the contents of all three files into one variable....?

After doing that, is it possible, for that one big file to contain just the dates (yyymm) that overlap? For instance, the `z.csv` file does not include the fourth month of the year, where `x` and `y .csv` files do. (to clarify, the first column of the one big file is `yyymm` and due to different labels in the excel sheets, we are considering "score" in the same way as "inv_sent" and "con_sent"  and so these three comprise the second column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the a view of the data frame with just a subset of columnts, you may use item slicing notation to select the columns you want.  E.g.:

```
z_reduced = z[['yyyymm','score']]
```

If you want it in a new data frame rather than a view on the original you can use:

```
z_copied = z[['yyyymm','score']].copy()
```

Then to merge all dataframes, you likely want to use the `merge` method.  Something like the following will probably get you what you need:

```
x.merge(y, on='yyyymm').merge(z_copied, on='yyyymm')
```

Merge by default works like an inner join in SQL.  You can also pass a `how` parameter that will allow you to do effectively the same as a left, right, or outer join if you want.